# How to determine if $match is in $string?

Tags: php, string

```
$string = "Test String for the test";
$match = "test string";
```

How to determine if $match is in $string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`stripos`](http://php.net/stripos) to find the position of `$match` in `$string` with a case-insensitive search:

```
$pos = stripos($string, $match);
```

Note to compare this with a [type-safe comparison operator](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison) like `===` or `!==`. Because if `$match` is at the begin of `$string` like in this case, `stripos` returns `0` and `(boolean) 0 === false`.

Comment: what's the comparison? if $pos >= 0

Comment: @Scott B: Not, `false >= 0` is true. Use `$pos !== false` or `$pos === false`.

Answer (score 1):

use `strpos` to check if it is in the string. [API Link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

For case insensitive, use `stripos`. [API Link](https://www.php.net/stripos)

Answer (score 0):

Use `stristr($haystack, $needle)`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php

```
$boolean = stristr($string, $match);
```

Comment: So, technically this would return `"Test String for the test"`, but that will evaluate to `TRUE`.